# Anyone have good literature on buying bullet vs barbell returns?

Tags: fixed-income

I am trying to understand the concept, weighting schemes, real\$ vs fast\$ view, etc... On the desk today, I used some third party tool to run analysis on some trade ideas but I'm blindly running numbers based on different horizon yields. I would like to understand the process more.

Comment: If the two portfolios have the same dollar duration, then the dollar convexity of the Barbell portfolio is greater than that of the Bullet portfolio. So they behave differently in response to yield changes. The details depends on how yield changes over the horizon that you will hold the portfolios. Fabozzi Bond Markets, Analysis and Strategies has some discussion in Ch 19.

Answer (score 3):

A very detailed treatment can be found in Antti Ilmanen's "Understanding the Yield Curve: Part 5 - Convexity Bias and the Yield Curve." This piece of pretty easy to find on the Internet.

Another wonderful report is "Can Convexity Be Exploited" (Lehman Brothers Quantitative Portfolio Strategy 2006).

For regression-based weighting, refer to Bruce Tuckman's *Fixed Income Securities*.

For PCA-based weighting, refer to "Principles of Principal Components" (Salomon Smith Barney 2000) and "PCA for Interest Rates" (Morgan Stanley 2005).